# Php xml data to json encode in specific format

Tags: php, json, xml

This is my php file code where i am fetching data from thecatapi
i needed the specific format for datatable

```
$xml=file_get_contents('https://thecatapi.com/api/images/get?format=xml&results_per_page=3');
 $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);

 $datas=array();

$datas['rows'] = $xml->data->images;

echo json_encode($datas, true);
```

Output is:

```
{"total":50,
 "rows":{"image":[
            {"url":"https:\/\/thecatapi.com\/api\/images\/get.php?id=e0i",
            "id":"e0i",
            "source_url":"http:\/\/thecatapi.com\/?id=e0i"
            },
            {"url":"https:\/\/thecatapi.com\/api\/images\/get.php?id=MTYwNDE0MQ",
            "id":"MTYwNDE0MQ",
            "source_url":"http:\/\/thecatapi.com\/?id=MTYwNDE0MQ"
            },{
            "url":"https:\/\/thecatapi.com\/api\/images\/get.php?id=bon",
            "id":"bon",
            "source_url":"http:\/\/thecatapi.com\/?id=bon"
            }
            ]
        }
}
```

but i wanted in this json form

```
{
  "total": 800,
  "rows": [
    {
      "url": 0,
      "id": "Item 0",
      "source_url": "$0"
    },
    {
      "url": 0,
      "id": "Item 0",
      "source_url": "$0"
    },
    {
      "url": 0,
      "id": "Item 0",
      "source_url": "$0"
    },
```

Comment: What do you mean? Do you want just prettify json? if so, just use  JSON_PRETTY_PRINT option

Comment: As your required output bears no resemblance to the output you are starting from, we are going to struggle to be much help here

Comment: Please remember, we are not clairvoyant. We can only comment on what you show us, if that makes no sense, neither will any answers you might get

Comment: @NobbyNobbs no sir i don't want to just prettify it i have tried whole day to format the data in this format because the bootstrap data table is not accepting other format and i am not a expert in bootstrap datatable

Comment: In your _I want_ example you seem to have removed pretty much everything. Thats why I dont understand your example of what you want out of this process

Comment: sir its a json output from this url http://issues.wenzhixin.net.cn/examples/bootstrap_table/data

Comment: thats good some intelligent over smart people is just downgrading new users questions when they are not able to give answer they just downgrade the question.

Comment: many issues here, but for starters the second parameter on a json_encode is not meant to be boolean but options. Rather try something `JSON_PRETTY_PRINT + JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES + JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE`. Also, you are not encoding the right element.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just came up with an alternativ solution. Change this line:

```
$datas['rows'] = $xml->data->images;
```

to this:

```
$datas['rows'] = $xml->data->images->image;
```

otherwise you can still do this

**Decode the json string into an object and modify it suit your needs.**

```
$stdClassObject = json_decode($jsonData);

$stdClassObject->rows = $stdClassObject->rows->image;

$newJsonData = json_encode($stdClassObject, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($newJsonData);
echo '</pre>';
```

**New output:**

```
{
    "total": 50,
    "rows": [
        {
            "url": "https:\/\/thecatapi.com\/api\/images\/get.php?id=e0i",
            "id": "e0i",
            "source_url": "http:\/\/thecatapi.com\/?id=e0i"
        },
        {
            "url": "https:\/\/thecatapi.com\/api\/images\/get.php?id=MTYwNDE0MQ",
            "id": "MTYwNDE0MQ",
            "source_url": "http:\/\/thecatapi.com\/?id=MTYwNDE0MQ"
        },
        {
            "url": "https:\/\/thecatapi.com\/api\/images\/get.php?id=bon",
            "id": "bon",
            "source_url": "http:\/\/thecatapi.com\/?id=bon"
        }
    ]
}
```